# MPAndroidChart entries on current screen

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can I get entries on screen(not all) in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

What I need to use? ViewPortHandler or what? Do I need to left element on screen, and get low of him.(this is a candle chart)

I have silly issues play with width of candletick, cuz i have method for get min/max X cord on screen(left right candle).
But its only cord, not index of entry.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please use the "edit" button below your question to write what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

i found solution, but maybe its bad.

```
 float lowestVisibleX = mainChart.getLowestVisibleX();
        float highestVisibleX = mainChart.getHighestVisibleX();
  int left = (int) Math.ceil(lowestVisibleX);
        int right = (int) Math.ceil(highestVisibleX);
        List<Integer> indexCheck = new ArrayList<>();
        int loopCount = right - left;
        while (loopCount != 0) {
            indexCheck.add(new Integer(left));
            left++;
            loopCount--;
        }
        List<CandleEntry> entriesOnScreen = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer in : indexCheck) {
            entriesOnScreen.add(candleDataSet.getValues().get(in));
        }
```